# Proof of variable change second order derivative (chain rule)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, change-of-variable

given that u = f(y) and y = g(x), could anyone prove that
$$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \frac{du}{dy} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2u}{dy^2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$?

I've tried to use the chain rule, but this is all I've got:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} \right) = \frac{du}{dy}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{dy}{dx}  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dy}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Now, just notice that (by chain rule again)
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{du}{dy}\right) &= \dfrac{d}{dy} \left( \dfrac{du}{dy}\right) \cdot  \dfrac{dy}{dx}\\
&= \dfrac{d^2u}{dy^2} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align}
If you plug this into your expression, you'll get the desired form.

---

If it makes it clearer, temporarily call $v = \dfrac{du}{dy}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dv}{dx} &= \dfrac{dv}{dy} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dx} \\
&= \dfrac{d^2u}{dy^2} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align}

Comment: That's it, thanks. However, you've got a typo in the first line of the first equation (I guess), it's d/dy (du/dy) . dy/dx. As soon as you correct it I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @R.Thomes Ah yes of course, thanks for catching that